# Image border around HTML Page in IE7 and up

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to have a border around the entire HTML page something like a [photo frame](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6ncmIY0j4uQ/T9TAs4V4-XI/AAAAAAAADj0/X8FrUj53CQA/s320/FlowerFrame6.png)

there's a [solution](http://css-tricks.com/examples/BodyBorder/kottke.php) but it doesnt work for IE7+
anybody have any ideas?

**edit 1**

thank you for the replies, i think i didnt explain my problem clearly. i've included a sample design

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/604317/test.jpg

basically it's frame that surrounds the page

**edit 2**

I've added a fiddlejs which i got from @Sebastian Graz, its almost there but the frame need to fill the content not the only the window

http://jsfiddle.net/xzqDQ/1/

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
background: url('http://f.cl.ly/items/1P2Q1u0O2P44082N1L3a/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-04%20at%204.25.01%20PM.png');
position: fixed;
}
#left, #right {
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    }
#left { left: 0; }
#right { right: 0; }

#top, #bottom {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    }
#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: it may seems stupide, but why not use a body background color as the "border color" and set body padding to the size of the border you expect. Then all you need to add is an extra child tag to contain all your content like a "smaller body"

Comment: thanks, but i dont think it'll work though, i've updated my entry please check

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    border:50px solid orange;
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: is not a solid border, the frame has to have a pattern or some sort.



imagine http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6ncmIY0j4uQ/T9TAs4V4-XI/AAAAAAAADj0/X8FrUj53CQA/s320/FlowerFrame6.png around the entire page

Answer (score 0):

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/xzqDQ/

Css:

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
background: url('http://f.cl.ly/items/1P2Q1u0O2P44082N1L3a/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-04%20at%204.25.01%20PM.png');
position: fixed;
}
#left, #right {
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    }
#left { left: 0; }
#right { right: 0; }

#top, #bottom {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    }
#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but is it possible to add patter into the border-box? i thought border-box just for dimension rules. i've updated my entry please check

Comment: Yes indeed - check my fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/xzqDQ/ if you wish to have more control over where the background goes you can create 4 separate image files and add them to the top,left,right,bottom divs accordingly

Comment: thank you, yes i've tried that too, but the problem is when the content is long the frame just stuck there http://jsfiddle.net/xzqDQ/1/